# Customizable math spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have a math mode expression which requires a spacing that doesn't seem to be possible using just the spacing commands like `\!`, `\;`, etc. The closest appears to be `\!\!`, but it has too much space. Is there a way to customize spacing in math mode?

Comment: You can use `\mkern`, for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/mkern.htm

Comment: Use `\mkern  x mu` and choose the value of $x$ that fits your  needs.

Comment: without any example code impossible to guess your issue but you can use whatever space you like, no need for `\!\!`  you can use `\mspace{5mu}` or whatever

Comment: `\!\!` is negative space of `2\thinmuskip`  `\!\!\!\;` is space of  `\thickmuskip-3\thinmuskip`  why would you use these amounts?

Comment: Roughly speaking `\!` is -3 and `\:` is +4 and `\;` is +5. Thus `\!\:` is +1 and `\!\;` is +2 and `\,` is +3 ... and so on. Similarly, `\!\!\;` is -1 and `\!\!\:` is -2 ...

Comment: Not really, `\:` and `\;` are rubber glue lengths of variable size, but you can use the values directly no need to use weird combinations of the named lengths. Also one should try to avoid explicit spacing in almost all cases.

Comment: @Sebastiano why `\mkern` ? that will lose the plus and minus components ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle With a lot of sincerity I use often `\mkern` and I have written this command.

Comment: @Sebastiano yes but `\mskip 2mu plus 1mu minus 2mu`  is half of `\:`  `\mkern  2mu plus 1mu minus 2mu` is a kern of 2mu and then typesets  `plus 1mu minus 2mu` as text, so why `\mkern` rather than `\mskip` (or the latex version, `\mspace`) ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right. I have understood another information that I not knew. I have seen only your comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't give many clues but the default values are

```
\thinmuskip=3mu
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu
```

Although they may be changed by the document class or packages you are using.

so `\!\!` is `-6mu` and `\!\!\!\;` is a stretch length of `-4mu plus 5mu` (that is will be between `-4mu` and `+1mu` depending on the surrounding context).

It is not clear how you are using these values, but (with amsmath) you can use `\mspace{..}` with arbitrary mu values or (almost always preferable) you can adjust the values of the three mathskips to change the spacing in all cases without adding explicit spacing to each formula.

Note that the reason for the named space commands like `\,` is they match the space added by TeX's automatic spacing between atoms of different classes, so you can emulate or negate that spacing in some contexts.

```
x\,x
```

will always have the same space that Tex adds automatically to a construct such as

```
\log x
```

so whatever values a document class gives to `\thinmuskip` these constructs will change in a consistent way.

However a construct such as

```
x\!\!\;x
```

Gives no consistency at all: it might be a positive or negative space depending on the values set for `\thinmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` any formula using such a construct is fragile and probably would need editing if typeset with different fonts using different spacing defaults.

If you really need to add explicit space distinct from the named spaces, `amsmath` provides `\mspace` as a LaTeX syntax version of `\mskip` (cf `\vspace` and `\hskip`) so you can use

```
x\mspace{6mu plus 2mu}x
```

Or whatever space you need.

Comment: Does fractional mu work too?

Comment: @Someone yes, you could have just tried it:-) `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}\begin{document}\Huge zz\\$x\mspace{2mu}x$\\$x\mspace{.5mu}\mspace{1.5mu}\mspace{.5mu}x$\end{document}`

Comment: What's the point of using `plus` and `minus` in `\mspace`?

Comment: @Someone the default values are stretchy not fixed so you may want to specify stretchy values  6mu plus 2mu has a natural length of 6mu and can stretch to 8mu on lines that need stretching (minus components are shrink  amounts)