# How can I make a smaller negative space than \!?

Tags: kerning

I noticed that the spacing in "(A" in my document looks too wide. I tried adjusting it with "(!A", but that looks too thin. How can I make a negative space that's thinner than `\!`?

(A: [image]

(\!A: [image]

Comment: Apart from commands like `\!` you can also always use `\kern` (or `\mkern`) with negative values.

Comment: @cabohah Thank you, I'll look into those commands!

Comment: In text mode, `\!` is equivalent to `\kern-1.66667em`

Comment: @egreg That sounds like a lot, maybe it's another unit? `(\kern-1pt A` was just right for me, thanks!

Comment: @Anna The `em` unit depends on the current font. Anyway, I'd not add the negative spacing.

Comment: Related questions [What commands are there for horizontal spacing? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing) ■ [math mode - More spacing options than `\!`, `\,`, `\:`, `\;` - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566288/more-spacing-options-than)